# Getting different url requests to API depending on how I've gotten to the page

Tags: ember.js

I'm getting some curious behaviour that I can't figure out the reason for.

This is my router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('mapPieceSets', { path: '/map-pieces' }, function () {
        this.resource('mapPieceSet', { path: '/:mapPieceSet_id' }, function () {
            this.resource('mapPiece', { path: '/:mapPiece_id' });
        });
    });
});
```

I reload the app from the home page `#/` then navigate down to the `mapPiece` route, I get these URLs requested:

- `[Domain]/api/mapPieceSets/`
- `[Domain]/api/mapPieces/1/`
- `[Domain]/api/mapPieces/2/`

And it all works fine (`mapPieceSets` returns a list of `mapPieceSet` which have a list of `mapPiece` against them)

However, if I reload the whilst on a `mapPiece` routed page, then I get this URL:

- `[Domain]/api/mapPieceSets/`
- `[Domain]/api/mapPieceSets/?mapPieceSet_id=1`
- `[Domain]/api/mapPieces/?mapPiece_id=1`

So switching from `/:id=` to `?id=`, which isn't working on my end points (that's a side issue which I need to resolve), but just wondering why the URLs changed what they're requesting, and why we get a request to `mapPieceSets/?mapPieceSet_id=1` when the whole of that object is returned within the response from `mapPieceSets/`

(If you need any other snippets of code from my app, let me know and I can put them in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly common confusion.  When you're in your app navigating around you're often using a `link-to` which is then telling ember to use the specified model when visiting the route.  When you're refreshing the page, Ember has to divine the models using the url `/apimapPieceSets/3/2`.  At that point it will go to each route `MapPieceSetsRoute`, `MapPieceSetRoute`, and `MapPieceRoute` and hit each model hook passing in any associated params.  So what you need to tell Ember how to do, is how to load a `mapPieceSet`, and `mapPiece` properly.  You'll need to setup a model hook for both of those.

```
App.MapPieceSetsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  // I don't know if you're using Ember Data, but I'm going to assume you are
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('mapPieceSet', params.mapPieceSet_id);
  }
});
```

From what you said, it sounds like the model is already available client side from the `mapPieceSets`.  In that case, you can use the `modelFor` method to get a parent's route's model and get your model.

```
App.MapPieceSetsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  // I don't know if you're using Ember Data, but I'm going to assume you are
  model: function(params){
    return this.modelFor('mapPieceSets').get('properyWithMapPieces').findBy('id', params.mapPieceSet_id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Ahh, yes, I forgot about trying `modelFor` thanks! Yes, you're correct I'm using Ember data, thanks!